# How do I get a TabControl to use the full width of its parent in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have a tab control inside canvas. How do I get a TabControl to use the full width of its parent?

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <sdk:TabControl Width="400" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <sdk:TabItem Header="myResponse">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </sdk:TabItem>
    </sdk:TabControl>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<Canvas>` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Without talking about why you are using a `canvas` in the first place, I would recommend you read about `width` and `height` properties in WPF.

In your example, the width is set specifically to a defined amount of pixel. With this, the TabControl will not scale. You should use relative values like `*` and `auto` and work with `margins` where they are needed. This tutorial could be a start: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-layout-size-width-and-height/